# jquery function to intersect arrays by the same elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Does exists a JS or jQuery function to intersect 2 arrays, for example:

```
var array1 = [1,2,3,4,5];
var array2 = [2,4,8,9,0];
var result = someFun(array1, array2);
//result = [2,4];
```

sure I can make it manually, but maybe exists a shorter way.

Comment: The answer to your actual question (whether such a function exists) is: no.

Comment: @FelixKling Ok, thanks, that what I sought

Answer (score 34):

Since you have jQuery tag:

```
$(array1).filter(array2);
```

Or:

```
$.map(array1, function(el){
  return $.inArray(el, array2) < 0 ? null : el;
})
```

Or (not for IE8 or less):

```
array1.filter(function(el) {
    return array2.indexOf(el) != -1
});
```

Example:

```
> array1 = [1,2,3,4,5];
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
> array2 = [2,4,8,9,0];
[2, 4, 8, 9, 0]
> array1.filter(function(el) {
    return array2.indexOf(el) != -1
  });
[2, 4]
```

Comment: Where is the jQuery here?

Comment: Hm... I'm not sure that `filter` will work in IE8 or less without jQuery, but I might be wrong.

Comment: Then you should provide jQuery solution, since `array.filter()` is a prototype method. jQuery method is called `$.grep()`.

Comment: Not sure what all the fuss is about.  I can use "filter", "not", and so on with a jQuery array.  no issues.  This is the intersection, true, but also answers a more general question

Comment: Never realized `$(array1).filter(array2)` could do pure array manipulations. That helped!

Comment: You can also get rid of the dependency on the variable array2 in the outer scope using the second argument to filter():
`array1.filter (function (v) { return this.indexOf(v) >= 0; }, array2)`

Answer (score 1):

This Should work

```
var alpha = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    beta = [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

$.arrayIntersect = function(a, b)
{
    return $.grep(a, function(i)
    {
        return $.inArray(i, b) > -1;
    });
};
console.log( $.arrayIntersect(alpha, beta) );
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/i_like_robots/KpCt2/)